# htaccess: put two similar RewriteCond in one and then take "all others, than that"

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to unite these two lines into one and put NOT before that one.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /administration/([^/]+)\ HTTP/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /administration/\ HTTP/ [NC]
```

So, it will be "take everything, that doesn't go through that two RewriteCond, and exclude everything that does".

Thank you.

Comment: `NOT(X OR Y)` equals `(NOT X) AND (NOT Y). So remove the `,OR` and add a `!` in front of `/admin...`

Comment: You are absolutely right, but I asked about ONE LINE! Not a fair to downvote just because you didn't read the first string of my question:(  What about !(X||Y)==!X && !Y  - I know that since I'm 12.

Comment: That downvote wasn't me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution below combines both rules into one.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /administration/(\ |[^/\ ]+\ )  [NC]
```

If you want to match anything that does not match the above then negate it

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /administration/(\ |[^/\ ]+\ )  [NC]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Brilliant! That's exactly what I need! Ulrich, thanks a lot! Now my .htaccess file works how I want. Thank you everybody for your help for the last 10 days I asked questions regarding .htaccess.